# Função não acha texto em Tedit

Tags: delphi

Com o código abaixo estou tentando encontrar um texto em um `Tedit`,

```
procedure TForm2.CheckBox3Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
   begin
   existeCampo := false;
    begin
       for i := 1 to form1.variavel do
       begin
          if TEdit(form1.FindComponent('edt_variavel'+IntToStr(i))).Text = 'dose_adicional' then
           begin
            existeCampo := true;
            break;
            checkbox3.Checked := true;
           end;
         end;

      if existeCampo = false then
        begin
        Showmessage('Para utilizar essa opção, adicione uma variavel com o nome de "dose_adicional");
        Checkbox3.Checked :=false;
        end;
     end;
   end;
```

já fiz vários testes, e ele não encontra o texto, mesmo eu digitando corretamente no edit, por que isso acontece?

Comment: Existe um componente `edt_variavel<i>` ? Ele é um `TEdit` ou algum outro componente?
Qual o valor de `form1.variavel` ?
Qual é a utilidade daquele `x:=0;` no meio do nada?

Comment: sim existe, ele é um Tedit, form1.variavel por ser de 1 a 15.
O  x = 0 foi retirado.

Comment: é só um chute, por isso não vou colocar como resposta, mas tenta colocar `as TEdit` no retorno do `FindComponent`

Eu acho que você está tendo problema porque ele tá transformando o retorno do `FindComponent` que é um `TComponent` em um `TEdit`, e aí no caso ele tem o `name`, mas não vai ter o `text`

Comment: mas eu faço a mesma coisa pra receber o texto e jogar dentro de um array, por que nao funcionaria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testei e encontrei um problema na sua codificação na parte do for, os componentes começam sempre em 0 (zero) e não em 1 (um), talvez se o texto dose_adicional fosse o promeiro ele nao cairia no IF. E tambem alterei para uma forma mais pratica, mas a sua esta funcional.

Na parte do break passei uma linha abaixo, caso contrario a sua checkbox nao ficara checada.

```
procedure TForm2.CheckBox3Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
begin
   existeCampo := false;

   for I := 0 to Componentcount-1 do
      begin
         if Components[i] is TEdit then
            begin
               if TEdit(Components[i]).Text = 'dose_adicional' then
                  begin
                     existeCampo := true;
                     checkbox3.Checked := true;
                     break;
                  end;
            end;
      end

  if existeCampo = false then
     begin
        Showmessage('Para utilizar essa opção, adicione uma variavel com o nome de "dose_adicional");
        Checkbox3.Checked :=false;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: negativo, o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: não da uma mesangem, ele simplesmente nao encontra.

Comment: cara no meu teste passou, coloquei uns 5 edit na tela e coloquei palavras aleatorias e o dose adicional e passou de boa... debuque o codigo para ver se ele passa por cada edit ou outro componente e pega o text certo tambem

Comment: realmente, fiz o mesmo teste e funcionou..então a resposta ta funcional..vou ver o que está acontecendo obrigado.